# Foundation For Emails Responsive Email Inliner V2 breaks TWIG Layout

Tags: html, email, twig, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation For Emails Responsive Email Inliner V2, to be found at: http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner-v2.html

I get a problem with my TWIG code:

```
<table class="row collapse">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    {% for alternative in alternatives %}
        <th class="small-6 large-4 columns">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    {{ alternative.name }}
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

becomes

```
{% for alternative in alternatives %} {% endfor %}
<table class="row collapse" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
        <th class="small-6 large-4 columns" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 16px; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; text-align: left; width: 193.33333px;">

            {{ alternative.name }}
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the for-Construct is at top of the table-Tag so it's not wrapped around the th-Tag after inlining.

Anyone got an idea what to do? Drives me crazy ;)

Comment: You're pasting you Twig code in the inliner? Why not pasting the rendered HTML code instead?

Comment: Hi Veve!
The template is used for X e-mails, for 3 shops, each of it got 6 languages. It's totally dynamic so I don't have the final HTML at this moment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your html code is bad formatting:

```
                                <table class="row collapse">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                {% for alternative in alternatives %}
                                    <th class="small-6 large-4 columns">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <!-- add here td or th tags -->
                                                <td>
                                                  {{ alternative.name }}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually has to do with some error in the code:

You can also use the original one:
http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html

Comment: Thx rafibomb! Does it mean some error in my TWIG or within the inliner?